# Creating document in Open XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

Take a look at WordprocessingDocument class in the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging I saw the Create method that receive as parameter a string path and a type that are a WordProcessingDocumentType.

WordProcessingDocumentType

```
public enum WordprocessingDocumentType
{
    // Summary:
    //     Word Document (*.docx).
    Document = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Word Template (*.dotx).
    Template = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Word Macro-Enabled Document (*.docm).
    MacroEnabledDocument = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Word Macro-Enabled Template (*.dotm).
    MacroEnabledTemplate = 3,
}
```

So, I can't build a .doc file, or put some compatibility with the Word 97-2003 as .doc format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, pre 2007 doesn't use the openxml file format.

Comment: I'm asking because my client has Word 2003. And I'm trying generate via OpenXML a .doc word file format, but he complains that appears error when he will open or edit the file.

Comment: If you are limited to using the openxml format it will only work with office 2007 and newer. However there are plugins for office 2003 that converts docx files to doc on the fly when you open them. If your client can install that plugin the problem would be solved. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/redir/DC010205246.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010044473

Answer (score 0):

Word 2003 was the first version of Word to introduce an XML format. However, later versions (2007 and 2010) uses a very different XML format:

- **2003**: WordProcessingML or WordML - the entire file is stored in one monolithic XML file.
- **2007/2010**: OpenXML - multiple XML files are combined into a package (a ZIP file).

If you want to create WordML files you can download [Office 2003: XML Reference Schemas](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=101) from Microsoft.

To create OpenXML documents you need to download the [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) from Microsoft.